# PowerShell Extract urls from strings

Tags: regex, string, powershell, http, url

I retrieved all urls from a word document and saved it to a variable. The URLs are trimmed by looking for the http keyword.
However, when there is a headline or any kind of other text between the urls, all the text is getting added to the previous url and destroys the url:
For instance:

```
[https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html][1]

Headline
=========
[https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html][1]
```

With my Sourcecode, I get the following URL/ String:
`[https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.htmlHeadline][2]`

However, that is not a valid url and I would to check the status codes of the urls afterwards, but do not succeed because of invalid url-strings.

```
$hyperlinks = $x.document.body.innertext         # all text as a single string (no breaks)

$hyperlinks `
  | Select-String -Pattern 'https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)' -AllMatches `
  | % { $_.Matches } `
  | % { $_.Value } `
  | Sort-Object `
  | Get-Unique

$array = $hyperlinks -split '(?=http)'
```

Comment: Another one found this strange `[-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*` regex. Where do you get it from all the time? Do not trust such patterns where unnecessary characters are doubled. When someone was writing this pattern, they could think the pattern inside a character class can match sequences of characters and that is wrong.

Comment: Wiktor I tried it out - sadly the text after the url gets added to the url and makes the url invalid - the further text is added after the file extension

Comment: What did you try out, the regex you found online? It is not a good regex. You need to either look for a better regex, or construct your own if you can come up with exact specs for your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$hyperlinks = $x.document.ChildNodes.p.innertext

$hyperlinks = $hyperlinks | Select-String -Pattern '(ftp|ftps|sftp|http|https)://(\S)*' -AllMatches `
  | % { $_.Matches } `
  | % { $_.Value } `
  | Sort-Object `
  | Get-Unique


$array = $hyperlinks | foreach-object { $_ -split '(?=http://)' }
$array = $array | foreach-object { $_ -split '(?=https://)' }
$array = $array | foreach-object { $_ -split '(?=ftp://)' }
$array = $array | foreach-object { $_ -split '(?=sftp://)' }
$array = $array | foreach-object { $_ -split '(?=ftps://)' }

$array = $array | where-object { -not [String]::IsNullOrEmpty($_) }
```

Comment: With the sample input text, your code returns `https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html][1]`, i.e. the URL isn't correctly extracted. Given that the `$hyperlinks = ...` pipeline returns only protocol-prefixed strings, the `-split` operations are unnecessary no-ops. (As an aside: the multiple `foreach-object` calls are inefficient, you could just chain them in a single pipeline; that said, you can directly chain `-split` operations, and even consolidate the  multiple ones into a single one with alternation (`|`), as you're already doing with `Select-String`).

Answer (score 0):

Given what answer you accepted, it looks like a complex regex that strictly matches only valid URLs isn't necessary, which allows you to greatly simplify the solution:

Given that all your URLs are enclosed in `[...]` and followed by, e.g. `[1]`, all you need is a lookahead assertion (`(?=…)`) to find the end of a URL:

```
$hyperlinks = $x.document.body.innertext 

$array = 
  [regex]::Matches($hyperlinks, '\bhttps?://.+(?=]\[\d+])').Value | 
  Sort-Object -Unique
```

- For a detailed explanation of the regex and the option to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/7a3CJ7/2).
- [`[regex]::Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace) is used in combination with [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) to extract the text (`.Value`) from all matches.

  - Using a .NET API directly is currently necessary (PowerShell (Core) 7.4); [GitHub issue #7867](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7867) is a **green-lit feature request to implement a `-matchall` operator**, which would allow for a more PowerShell-idiomatic solution, but no one has stepped up to implement it so far.